# Global biomes data set - eg. Rain Green Forest, Succulent Thorn Woods, Highland Scrub

Tags: data-request, global, land-cover

**Data request**

I'm looking for a **global** dataset of biomes but I need to cover quite specific categories that can be identified as termite habitats, as described in [Sanderson (1996)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248816877_Biomass_of_termites_and_their_emissions_of_methane_and_carbon_dioxide_A_global_database):

- Rain Green Forest
- Tropical Rain Forest
- Tropical Montane Forest Complexes/Tropical Seasonal Forest
- Temperate Forest
- Savannah/Hot Grassland
- Succulent/Thorn Woods
- Cultivated Land: Farmland, Crops
- Temperate Grassland/Shortgrass Prairie
- Mediterranean Tree/Scrub/Highland Scrub
- Desert/Semidesert
- Eucalyptus/Acacia

Or any other land cover data that can be mapped to these biomes. Generally, any land cover data that is more detailed than the usual Forest-Crop-Grassland scheme will help.

**Context**

My aim is to calculate global methane emissions from termites based on the methodology by Sanderson (1996) but possibly with newer data. For this purpose I need to identify termite habitats around the world.

**Format**

Ideally a NetCDF file but I will do with pretty much anything (ideally in the resolution of 0.5 deg).

**Non-answer**

The mentioned paper cites the **Olson database** from the year 1989. If I step aside from the fact that I was not able to find the actual data (I did find some [data](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.ECOSYSTEMS/.Olson/class/datafiles.html) but it contains different categories from those written in the paper), it's still a quite old data set, so anything more up to date would be appreciated.